# Is there a way to file a criminal complaint to report fraud and copyright incidents in Germany anonymously?

Tags: germany, criminal-procedure, claims

Is there a way to file a criminal complaint to report fraud and copyright incidents in Germany anonymously?

What is the right way and what requirements are needed to present evidence via email or certified mail? What can be reviewed and what can't?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I know of a case were certain person has committed many violations of author's rights affecting hundreds of authors, and when I say hundreds, I only mean those who are aware, they have all the evidence compiled and they are all witnesses.

Comment: Those affected authors are musical authors... Do you have any suggestion? Any intern or lawyer interested in a case like this?

Answer (score 2):

A formal criminal complaint would be a *Strafanzeige*. This requires the injured party to make a statement. Or you could make an anonymous tip, which may or may not cause the police and prosecution to act.

In German law there are crimes which are only prosecuted at the request of the injured party ([Antragsdelikt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antragsdelikt)) and crimes where the police have to follow any credible evidence (even if the victim does not cooperate). In between are crimes which may be prosecuted either on the basis of a criminal complaint or because the prosecution sees a public interest.

If you are serious about making a complaint without revealing your identity, talk to a German lawyer to help you.

Comment: what do you suggest for a case were certain person committed many violations of author's rights affecting hundreds of authors? there is a lot of evidence compiled by the affected parties, are you lawyer or passant? might you be interested?

Comment: Inform some of the copyright holders. **They** have reasonably effective legal remedies. The police is unlikely to get into copyright matters without a complaint. You might also send a tip to a police hotline, but I don't expect this to rise to the point where the police acts without the injured party.